# Unable to add 'Price' field to SubscriptionItemsParams

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I am trying to update the price of a Stripe subscription with Golang as shown here:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade

I copied and pasted the following code from the docs, but substituted in the correct Stripe key, subscription ID, and price ID:

```golang
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
stripe.Key = "sk_test_51LsirAKpk5W1QCoV3cKpwMabHz8VzurJnNNSmvBkr4zRaicCJFsz8NL7HyvJ7EC61CuKc7eHjMLHqjK1C9Xl6RpD00X5YHcRBk"

subscription, err := sub.Get("sub_49ty4767H20z6a", nil)
params := &stripe.SubscriptionParams{
  CancelAtPeriodEnd: stripe.Bool(false),
  ProrationBehavior: stripe.String(string(stripe.SubscriptionProrationBehaviorCreateProrations)),
  Items: []*stripe.SubscriptionItemsParams{
    {
      ID: stripe.String(subscription.Items.Data[0].ID),
      Price: stripe.String("price_CBb6IXqvTLXp3f"),
    },
  },
}
subscription, err = sub.Update(subscription.ID, params)
```

This yields the following error:

```
unknown field 'Price' in struct literal of type "github.com/stripe/stripe-go".SubscriptionItemsParams
```

Any ideas where else the Price field might go?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by specifying a Stripe version in the import by changing this:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/customer"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/sub"
)
```

to this:

```golang
import (
    stripe "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v74"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v74/customer"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v74/subscription"
)
```

It also appears that for v74,

```golang
ProrationBehavior: stripe.String(string(stripe.SubscriptionProrationBehaviorCreateProrations)),
```

should be changed to

```golang
ProrationBehavior: stripe.String(string(stripe.SubscriptionSchedulePhaseProrationBehaviorCreateProrations)),
```